# Mask animation with circular div in css

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a google-material-design-like button with a ripple effect but my animation is showing up as a square shape when I want it to be circle.

This happens because the animation reaches a size bigger than the div it is in, and then fills the edges of the outer div making it look like a square. Is there a way to set the outer div itself to be a circle, because even though I've set `border-radius: 50%`, the div itself (not the shape created within the div) is still a square.

html:

```
<div id="imgs">
    <div id="button"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#button{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.drop{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: hsl(180, 40%, 80%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.drop.animate {
  -webkit-animation-name: ripple;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  100% {opacity: 0; transform: scale(2.5);}
}
```

I thought that giving the `#button` the property of `overflow: hidden` would create the masked effect, but it didn't.

javascript:

```
var parent, ink, d, x, y;## Heading ##
$("#imgs #button").click(function(e){
    element = $(this);
    if(element.find(".drop").length === 0)
        element.prepend("<span class='drop'></span>");

    drop = element.find(".drop");
    drop.removeClass("animate");

    if(!drop.height() && !drop.width())
    {
        d = Math.max(element.outerWidth(), element.outerHeight());
        drop.css({height: d, width: d});
    }

    x = e.pageX - element.offset().left - drop.width()/2;
    y = e.pageY - element.offset().top - drop.height()/2;

    //set the position and add class .animate
    drop.css({top: y+'px', left: x+'px'}).addClass("animate");
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stecd/P2kdA/) where you can see the effect the above code generates. How can I alter it so that the ripple animation shows up round (confined to the round button) as opposed to squared (expanding over the button's boundaries)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is caused by a reported bug in chrome. There isn't a fix yet but there is a simple work-around that doesn't affect the aesthetic.

You need to add a transform to the element: `-webkit-transform: rotate(0.000001deg);` It can be so small as to be imperceptible, but that should be enough to fix it by promoting the paint order of the elements.

```js
var parent, ink, d, x, y;
$("#imgs #button").click(function(e) {
  element = $(this);
  if (element.find(".drop").length === 0)
    element.prepend("<span class='drop'></span>");

  drop = element.find(".drop");
  drop.removeClass("animate");

  if (!drop.height() && !drop.width()) {
    d = Math.max(element.outerWidth(), element.outerHeight());
    drop.css({
      height: d,
      width: d
    });
  }

  x = e.pageX - element.offset().left - drop.width() / 2;
  y = e.pageY - element.offset().top - drop.height() / 2;

  //set the position and add class .animate
  drop.css({
    top: y + 'px',
    left: x + 'px'
  }).addClass("animate");
});
```

```css
#button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0.000001deg); /* This is the important bit */
}
.drop {
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: hsl(180, 40%, 80%);
  border-radius: 90%;
  transform: scale(0);
}
.drop.animate {
  -webkit-animation-name: ripple;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2.5);
    border-radius: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgs">
  <div id="button"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a breakdown of the bug:

### https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157218

Comment: It works by promoting the paint order of the divs. There is a comment on the bug explaining the diagnosis which leads to the work-around.